# Jenkins 2.319.1: use custom workspace

Tags: jenkins, workspace

I have to create a custom workspace for only one Jenkins build to get files form Git.
The standard workspace folder is : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
For testing purposes I would like to set the workspace into /tmp/workspace/test
I have created the folders and give access.

In the build configuration I have clicked on "Use custom workspace", set my custom folder, apply (see the green popup "Saved") and Save it.

But when I run the build:

- the custom workspace haven't been used.
- the build is made in the "default" folder /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
- when I open the configuration of the build the "Use custom workspace" is no more selected.

Is there something specific to do to be able to update the custom workspace for a specific build ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Jenkins issue:
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67638

The workaround is to go onto your Jenkins machine, find the config.xml for the relevant project, and add the customWorkspace tag manually

```
<customWorkspace>myWorkspace/</customWorkspace>
```

Then restart Jenkins (Easiest way is to go to `<YourJenkinsUrl>/safeRestart`)